# Returning self in a function gives me nil in swift

Tags: ios, delegates, swift

I have implemented in a playground a GreetingDelegate protocol with a function sayHi (hypothetically)and a class Data that conforms with said protocol.

I also have a class named Class that has a delegate that conforms to the GreetingDelegate,  another sayHi function, and a function that determines if who shall respond to sayHi.

If Class doesn't have a delegate triggers his own version of the sayHi function but if the delegate exists triggers the delegate's version of the function.

```
protocol GreetingDelegate {
  func sayHi(name: String) -> String
}

class Class {
  var delegate: GreetingDelegate?

  func sayHi(name: String) -> String {
    return "Hello, \(name)"
  }

  func target() -> Any {
    if let delegate = delegate {
      return delegate
    }
    return self
  }
}

class Data: GreetingDelegate {

  func sayHi(name: String) -> String {
    return "Hi, \(name)"
  }
}

let classInstance = Class()
classInstance.sayHi("Matt")

classInstance.target()

let dataInstance = Data()
dataInstance.sayHi("Matt")

classInstance.delegate = dataInstance
classInstance.sayHi("Matt")

classInstance.target()
```

The strange part is when I call the target function before assigning any delegate it return nil when it should return itself. Really would appreciate help on this problem.

I attach a picture of the results of the playground if it be any help.[image]

**UPDATE #1**

When I change the return type of target() to AnyObject it doesn't return nil but it doesn't accept delegate as a return result.

Comment: Maybe `return self` isn't getting hit?  try returning something else to make sure it isn't always hitting `return delegate`, which would be nil before you define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning {nil} because that's what all of the variables belonging to that instance of Class are (because delegate is an optional, it defaults to nil).  If you add another variable, such as

```
var num: Int = 1
```

to the class, it will return {nil, 1} instead.  So it is returning the object - not the class name, but basically a summary of its data members.

Comment: Can i ask you why delegate was not a valid return type for AnyObject?

Comment: I may be wrong about this but I think it's because GreetingDelegate is a protocol, which looks like it belongs to Any but not to AnyObject.

Comment: A solution might saying delegate is AnyObject that conforms to a protocol, but I don't think there is way to do that yet. Again, thank you a lot for the clarification

Comment: @AJ_1310: It's because the `GreetingDelegate` protocol is not restricted to classes; structs and enums can also conform to it. If you want to restrict it to classes, then you should declare it as `protocol GreetingDelegate : class { ... }` (formerly `@class_protocol`), and then it will be compatible with `AnyObject`.

Comment: Quite a bummer that it restricts its use that way although I could see how it encourages type safety. Thanks, at least now it's understandable the logic behind it

Answer (score 0):

In the first case calling `target` function before setting the delegate returning `self` instance with its `delegate` value as `nil`. **{nil}** means instance with delegate value is uninitialised.

In the second case calling `target` function after setting the delegate returning `self` instance with its `delegate` value as `Data` object. **{Data}** means with delegate value is set with a `Data` object.

Comment: should returning self return the object calling `target`?
I think this would only be the case if he was always returning `delegate`